# Access Multipart text file in Flask using React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I am trying to access the text file content once I send the "multipart" textfile using axios. How can I access it in flask.

```
        data = dict(request.form)

        print(data)
```

After doing this in flask, I get

```
{'file': '[object Object]'}
```

On the front/end or react, I do this:-

```
          formData.append('file',info.file)
          console.log(formData)

          const config1 = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          }
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/recipes', formData, config1)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);

        });
```

I am not able to access the text-file contents. I figured out that REACT is sending an object to flask. I am stuck on this for long and it is giving me nightmares. How do i access the file contents?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use `request.files` to retrieve file objects in flask.

And you should check if this `info.file` object is a file object `console.log(info.file)`.

Comment: Hi therer Thanks for the answer. I tried doing request.files. I got "{}". The info.file has



```
{uid: "rc-upload-1577337063706-8", lastModified: 1577262343000, lastModifiedDate: undefined, name: "a.txt", size: 10, …}
```